# How to Know the status when the user tries to turn on wifi in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, wifi

As per our company requirement we are preventing BB user using WiFi within the office for that i have to enable and disable blackberry WiFi over incoming sms. I am able to disable   by this code if it is on.

```
if ((wafs & RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN) != 0) {
        Radio.deactivateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);
    }
```

But my question is how to know when the user try to enable WiFi. so that i can put restriction.

I had tried **[WLANConnectionListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/WLANConnectionListener.html#networkConnected%28%29)** interfae.But did not able to do this.If possible give me some sample code.

Comment: As you mention in your question `WLANConnectionListener.networkConnected()` is the correct way of detecting when the device has connected to a Wi-Fi network. How come this doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Donturener... My question is how to restrict for specific time or within some specific location when the user try to enable WiFi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question in android this way .But In blackberry is there a way..?

```
         if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) 
    {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED==state)
    {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because whilst you may be able to intercept the Wi-Fi enable request made by the user, you cannot stop the user from shutting down and/or uninstalling your app.

Comment: Dear sir. it is possible to handle both the situations(Reboot and uninstall of app). Please give me some idea or sample code  to implement WLANConnectionListener in my apps.